# Git-fetch behaves differently if there is no local branch

Tags: git

When there is no local branch, to fetch a commit by commit hash, git will fetch all ancestors again (even when the ancestors are already in local git database).

But when there is a local branch pointing to one of the ancestors, git won't fetch them again.

Could anyone help explain why?  Is it a technical restriction, or by design?

I'm using git for Windows 2.42.0.

---

It can be reproduce by below steps:

1. There is 2 computers *A* and *B*, and their IP addresses are `10.0.0.1` (A) and `10.0.0.2` (B).
2. *B* starts git daemon in source code root directory.

   ```
   git daemon --export-all --enable=upload-archive --base-path=.
   ```
3. *A* initializes a git repository and fetches from *B* **by commit hash**.

   ```
   git init
   git fetch --no-tags --progress --prune -- git://10.0.0.2/ d3571ce95af4dc281f142add33384abc5e574671
   git checkout FETCH_HEAD
   ```
4. *B* commits an **empty commit** `15aab0fd8b937eb3bb01841693f35dcb75da2faf` based on the commit in last step (`d3571c`).

   ```
   git commit --allow-empty -m "An empty commit"
   ```
5. *A* fetch the empty commit by hash.

   ```
   git fetch --no-tags --progress --prune -- git://10.0.0.2/ 15aab0fd8b937eb3bb01841693f35dcb75da2faf
   ```
6. Here is puzzlement: git seems to try to get all objects all over again to fetch an *empty* commit.

   ```
   remote: Enumerating objects: 49535, done.
   remote: Counting objects: ...
   remote: Compressing objects: ...
   Receiving objects: ...
   ...
   ```
7. However, it will be a totally different situation when there is a local branch.

   ```bash
   # Create another empty commit 7c6e5dd1bacb3b48fdffba2ed096097eb172497d in B
   $ git commit --amend -m "Another empty commit"

   # Fetch the new empty commit in A after creating a local branch
   $ git branch whatever
   $ git fetch --no-tags --progress --prune -- git://10.0.0.2/ 7c6e5dd1bacb3b48fdffba2ed096097eb172497d
   remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
   ...
   ```

Comment: Does this happen if the two repos are on the same computer?

Comment: Likely to be helpful: https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol#_reference_discovery

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I made a try and it's the same if the two repos are on the same computer.